# Всплывающая подсказка у метода доставки в WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, sidebar

Мне нужно поставить подсказку, иконку «знак вопроса» рядом с вариантом выбора доставки «Flat Rate», чтобы при нажатии всплывало окно с описанием условий доставки.

У меня есть код, который показывает значок (на данный момент заменил его на текст «My Icon»), при нажатии на который всплывает окно.

```
function action_woocommerce_after_shipping_rate( $method, $index ) {
    
    // Compare (adjust as needed)
    if( $method->get_id() == 'flat_rate:1' ) {
        echo '<span class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">My Icon<span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">';
        echo dynamic_sidebar( 'tooltip_sidebar' );          
        echo '</span></span>';
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shipping_rate', 'action_woocommerce_after_shipping_rate', 10, 2 );
```

Скрипт для вплывающего окна:

```
<script>
// When the user clicks on <div>, open the popup
function myFunction() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
</script>
```

Стиль для всплывающего окна:

```
/* Popup container */
.popup {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* The actual popup (appears on top) */
.popup .popuptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 320px;
    background: #fff;
    color: #222;
    text-align: center; 
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 125%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3);
}

/* Popup arrow */
.popup .popuptext::after {
    content: "X";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 5%;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
}

/* Toggle this class when clicking on the popup container (hide and show the popup) */
.popup .show {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
    animation: fadeIn 1s
}

/* Add animation (fade in the popup) */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity:1 ;}
}
```

Также я регистрирую новую область для сайдбара, в котором вывожу условия доставки:

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'register_new_sidebar' );
function register_new_sidebar() {

    register_sidebar(
        array(
            'id' => 'tooltip_sidebar',
            'name' => 'Условия доставки',
            'description' => 'Добавьте ваши условия доставки',
            'before_widget' => '<div>',
            'after_widget' => '</div>',
            'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
            'after_title' => '</h3>'
        )
    );
}
```

Но тут возникает проблема. Под текстом с условиями доставки появляется цифра `1`, хотя ее в тексте просто нет. Скорее всего, это показывается id самого сайдбара, либо номер колонки с сайдбарами.

Видимо я неправильно добавил вывод сайдбара `echo dynamic_sidebar ('tooltip_sidebar');`. Может нужно добавить условия вывода этого сайдбара?

Хотя это еще не все. На странице оформления заказа в сплывающем окне показывается текст условий доставки и цифра `1`. А вот на странице корзины, выводится только цифра, без текста условий доставки. Но судя по хуку, на обоих страницах текст должен выводиться одинаково.

Подскажите, как все это можно исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замените строку

```
echo dynamic_sidebar( 'tooltip_sidebar' );
```

на

```
dynamic_sidebar( 'tooltip_sidebar' );
```

`dynamic_sidebar` возвращает bool, и нет никакого смысла печатать это значение.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и помощь! Все работает. Век живи, век учись )